# gnuplot-iostream built in windows with MinGW

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnuplot

This post is a follow-up with the previous one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781030/gnuplot-c-api-which-one).

As being suggested to use one among 4 choices, I picked gnuplot-iostream. So what I did includes:

- install MinGW
- boost for gcc
- build in MinGW

However, there is one missing library that I don't know where to find and add to the build. That is **libutil**

Googling shows that this lib is from libc6 package in Ubuntu.

Are those examples ([link](http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/)) in gnuplot-iostream supposed to build in Ubuntu?  is there a replacement version of libutil in windows

THanks for the help!

Comment: I built them with MinGW on win8 x64 and libutil is also involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libutil` is needed for the `openpty` function, which is missing in MinGW (and probably in Windows overall).  But `openpty` is only needed if you wish to intercept mouse clicks from gnuplot.  If you remove `-lutil` from the `Makefile` then you should be able to compile all but one of the example programs (all but `example-interactive`).

If you have a need for processing mouse clicks in the `gnuplot` window then let me know as there may be a way to avoid `openpty`.

Comment: for real! only interactive example has the error. I've succeeded building the others. THanks to your suggestion!